# Android push occasional failure

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have a cron job that runs every minute that sends a maximum of 60 GCM messages, occasionally (about 10 times per day), sending a push message fails with curl returning this error :

Curl failed: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to android.googleapis.com:443

I have not found any particular pattern or managed to track down any reason for this. All ports are open (pushing works all the other times). Has anybody encountered this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this issue, I fixed it by forcing curl to use SSSL V3. In PHP this is done via :

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);